# how to fetch name from enum in java

Tags: java, enums

I do have a enum class in java as follows

```
public enum SMethod {

/**
 * LEAVE IN THIS ORDER
 */
A    (true, true, true,false),
B    (true, true, false,false),
C    (true, true, false,false),
D    (false, false, false)

}
```

Another class have below method

```
private String getSMethod(boolean isSds) {
    if (isClsSds)
        return "A";
    else 
        return "B";
}
```

Currently this method return hard code value but string.But I want to return it using SMethod enum.I have written it as follows:

```
private SMethod getSMethod(boolean isSds) {
    if (isClsSds)
        return SMethod.A;
    else 
        return SMethod.B;
}
```

but my need is this method should return String.

Comment: SMethod.A.name() should give you the string.

Answer (score 2):

Use [name()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) method:

```
return SMethod.A.name();
```

To get the `String` name of the enum object.

Answer (score 2):

```
return SMethod.A.name(); will return string
```

see [**name()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) method

> Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

- [***`Enum.name()`***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29)
- [***`Enum.toString()`***](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString%28%29)

So you can use

```
public String getName(SMethod enm)
{
    return enm.name();
    // or enm.toString();
}
```